# Setting a model attribute to a value based on, but not equal to, the input in angular-formly

Tags: angular-formly

I'm trying to figure out how to parse a form entry to set the model attribute to something else; e.g., extracting the video ID of a youtube video from a URL input. Is there a way to use parsers/formatters (6.21 features?) to accomplish this easily? I hoped to find a good example for this, and maybe there is one somewhere, but perhaps this would make a good one if there's not.

[Here is a working example](http://jsbin.com/hijonipiji/edit?html,js,output) of what I'm attempting to accomplish, but in multiple steps and without the use of parsers. Any help adapting the code to set `model.videoID` from a URL in a single step (or fewer than 3 steps, at least) would be very appreciated. Thank you for your help with this and my other past questions. :)

Comment: I don't have time to give a proper answer right now, but look into angular's  `$parsers` API. angular-formly has a `parsers` property for types and fields that you can use (recently added).

Comment: @kentcdodds I think I've figured it out for my app, I'll work on this example now and post an answer. It was very easy, and I was expecting it to be much more complicated. Thanks for adding the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this was much easier than I expected to implement. [Here is the modification of the JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/volepukise/edit?html,js,output) which uses `parsers`, recently added with `angular-formly@6.21.0`, to extract the video ID from a YouTube URL in one function. It also, conveniently, validates itself!

Here is the relevant code, to summarize:

```
{
  key: 'vidid',
  type: 'input',
  parsers: [extractID],
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'YouTube Video',
    placeholder: 'Insert video URL here'
},
```

...

```
function extractID(value) {    
  if (value != undefined || value != '') {        
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = value.match(regExp);
    if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
      return match[2];
    }
  }
};
```